# how to get the first letter of the name and use it as a profile of the stores

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, laravel

I want to set the profile picture of the stores using the first letter of their store name.

Here's my blade

```
<?php
        $smestable = DB::table('sme_table')->get(); 
                foreach ($smestable as $s) {
                        $name   = $s->store_name;
                ?>

      <div class="item">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
          <span id="storename">{!! $name !!}</span>
          <div id="profile"></div>
          <h4 class="text-center">{!! $name !!}</h4>
          <h5 class="text-center">4000,00 RSD</h5>
        </div>
      </div>

      <?php } ?>
```

and here's my javascript

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
  var storename = $('#storename').text();
  var intials = $('#storename').text().charAt(0);
  var profile = $('#profile').text(intials);
});
  </script>
```

and here's my css

```
#profile {
width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
border-radius: 50%;
background: #512DA8;
font-size: 35px;
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
line-height: 150px;
margin: 20px 0;
}
```

I want to set every store's profile picture using the first letter of the store name but only one has given. Here's the result.

[heres my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zseCL.png)

Comment: You can do it using PHP itself `{{ $name[0] }}`

Comment: it doesn't work sir/ma'am

Comment: you are creating multiple <span id="storename">{!! $name !!}</span> with same id. html id are supposed to be unique on a page.

Comment: your id is same for all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change below line of your code :

`<div id="profile"></div>`

to

`<div id="profile"><?php echo substr ($name , 0 ,1 ); ?></div>`

This will pick the first character from name and show it at the time of rendering itself, so you will not require to do it in JS.

Comment: Oh my! it worked. thank you so much sir. I thought it's hard but you find the easy way... heheheh. cheers ^^

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Blade - do it at all.

`@foreach` + `{{ }}` instead of `{!! !!}`

```
@foreach ($smestable as $sme)
    <div class="item">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
            <span id="storename">{{ $sme->store_name }}</span>
            <div id="profile">{{ substr($sme->store_name, 0, 1) }}</div>
            <h4 class="text-center">{{ $sme->store_name }}</h4>
            <h5 class="text-center">4000,00 RSD</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: this works too...thank you so much sir for your response... ^^ cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

As the comments suggest, you can use PHP to extract the first character, strings can be treated as arrays like so:

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
        <span id="storename">{!! $name !!}</span>
        <div id="profile">{!! strtoupper($name[0]) !!}</div>
        <h4 class="text-center">{!! $name !!}</h4>
        <h5 class="text-center">4000,00 RSD</h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this works too sir. thank you so much for your response. cheers ^_^